# How do I set dependency propertly value programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

Consider this XAML:

```
<esri:ElementLayer Name="ElementLayer">
    <esri:ElementLayer.Children>

        <!--Editable textbox-->
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" esri:ElementLayer.Envelope="40,0,40,0"
            Text="Editable text" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
     </esri:ElementLayer.Children>
 </esri:ElementLayer>
```

I want to rewrite this in code. I have this so far:

```
var customLayer = this.mapControl.Layers["ElementLayer"] as ElementLayer;
if (customLayer == null) return;

foreach (var customMapItem in this.CustomLayerData)
{
    var tb = new TextBox();
    tb.DataContext = customMapItem;
    // TODO: How to set esri:ElementLayer.Envelope="40,0,40,0" ???
    customLayer.Children.Add(tb);
}
```

So, I need to set dependedncy property in code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is how to set the value of an attached `DependencyProperty` on a `DependencyObject`.

The basic syntax would look like this:

```
DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty, myValue);
```

In your case, it would be like this:

```
customMapItem.SetValue(ElementLayer.EnvelopeProperty, new Envelope(40,0,40,0));
```

However, they also implemented a standard helper function, so here is a better way to do it:

```
ElementLayer.SetEnvelope(customMapItem, new Envelope(40,0,40,0));
```